# Do I need to add SHA-1 fingerprint in my Firebase project?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

On Firebase there is a popup that shows my project can add fingerprint - **SHA1**.

As I only want to use some Firebase services like Realtime database, Authentication? Do I need to add a fingerprint to my project ??

The picture shows that SHA-1 is only needed when using some Google Play services like OAuth 2 client (Google-sign, Twitter sign-in, ...)

[Fingerprint popup on Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT4dQ.jpg)

Please help me with this, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need to add SHA-1 fingerprint in my Firebase project?

It depends on what services you're using because not all services require that. It is a mandatory requirement if you intend to use:

- [Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links)
- [Google Sign-In](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)
- [Phone number support in Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth)

> As I only want to use some Firebase services like Realtime database, Authentication? Do I need to add a fingerprint to my project?

For the Realtime Database, it is not a requirement. Regarding Authentication, it depends. If you intend to implement [Firebase sign-in with Google](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d), you need to generate that [SHA-1 fingerprint certificate](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-for-debug-mode-in-android-studio-c9df7ae2401b).

Comment: Hey Trung. Can I help you with other information?