# Do I need to fill SHA-1 if I am linking on Firebase an app that is already on Google Play Store?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, crashlytics

I have an app that is available on the Google Play Store and I want to add Crashlytics to my app. So first of all I have seen that I have to link my app with Firebase. When linking my app with Firebase, I have seen that I am asked to put the "SHA-1" signature (it says that it is optional but I don´t know if I have to add it). So my intention is to add Crashlytics to a newer version of my app and then update my app with that version on the Google Play Store so that my app with Crashlytics is available on the Google Play Store. So, should I need to add the "SHA-1" signature if I am using only Crashlytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SHA-1 fingerprint certificate is not mandatory when you want to add an application to a Firebase project. That means that not all Firebase services use that. However, it is indeed a requirement if you want to use [Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links), and [Google Sign-In](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) or [phone number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) support in Auth. Why? Because it is needed to be used for authentication and authorization. If you don’t want to use these services, adding the certificate SHA-1 is optional. Maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-for-debug-mode-in-android-studio-c9df7ae2401b) will also help.

Comment: I have seen a similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71263716/do-i-need-to-add-sha-1-fingerprint-in-my-firebase-project[link] and you awnser was "Are you willing to add the app to Google Play? " So my app is already on Google Play, so with that rhetorical question, I understand that if the app is published on Google Play, then I should use SHA-1... I am a confused because that awnser you made on a similar post...

Comment: To stop the confusion, I just deleted that comment. Crashlitics doesn't require an SHA-1 fingerprint.